# Deleting an item from a list in Common Lisp

Tags: list, common-lisp

I'm trying to write a function in Common Lisp that deletes an item from a list. Here's what I've written so far:

```
(defun aux-remove-fio (lst toremove)
   (if (equal (first lst) toremove)
       (pop lst)
       (aux-remove-fio (rest lst) toremove))))
```

When I test the function, here's the result:

```
CG-USER(49): a3
((1 (1 . 1) (1 . 2)) (2 (2 . 1) (1 . 2)))
CG-USER(50): (pop a3)
(1 (1 . 1) (1 . 2))
CG-USER(51): a3
((2 (2 . 1) (1 . 2)))
CG-USER(52): (setf a3 '((1 (1 . 1) (1 . 2)) (2 (2 . 1) (1 . 2))))
((1 (1 . 1) (1 . 2)) (2 (2 . 1) (1 . 2)))
CG-USER(53): (aux-remove-fio a3 '(1 (1 . 1) (1 . 2)))
(1 (1 . 1) (1 . 2))
CG-USER(54): a3
((1 (1 . 1) (1 . 2)) (2 (2 . 1) (1 . 2)))
```

Can anyone explain why my function isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Your function changes the value of its local variable, `lst` --- nothing more.

Here is a simpler example, showing the same thing:

```
(setq a3 '(1 2 3)) ; (1 2 3)
(defun foo (xs) (setq xs (cdr xs))) ; Change value of xs.

;; Change value of xs to (2 3).  Its initial value is the value of a3, i.e., (1 2 3)
(foo a3)
a3 ; => (1 2 3)
```

After `foo` is called, `a3` still points to the original cons cell whose car is 1 and whose cdr is the same cons cell as before, with car 2, etc.  All you have done i smake local variable `xs` point to the cdr of the cons cell it originally pointed to, which was the same cons cell that `a3` points to.

If you want your function to change the value of global variable `a3`, then do so directly:

```
(defun foo () (pop a3))
```

Or if you just want a function that pops the first element off of the list value of a special variable, then you have such a function: `pop` --- just use `(pop a3)`.

If you want a function that changes the value of a global variable that you pass it, then pass the variable (i.e., symbol) and not its value:

```
(defun foo (var)
  (let* ((val   (symbol-value var))
         (head  (car val)))
    (set var (cdr val))
    head))

(foo 'a3) ; Pop off a3's head and return it.
a3 ; Now a3 has lost its head.
```

This definition of `foo` is like a simple form of `pop`, except that it is a function, so evaluates its argument.

Answer (score 0):

This is my simple solution. I define a function in REPL

```
CL-USER> (defun remove-element (mylist n)
           (append
            (subseq mylist 0 n)
            (subseq mylist (1+ n))))
```

then run it (errors on your Lisp implementation may differ)

```
CL-USER> (remove-element '(1 2 3 4 5) 0)
(2 3 4 5)
CL-USER> (remove-element '(1 2 3 4 5) 1)
(1 3 4 5)
CL-USER> (remove-element '(1 2 3 4 5) 5)
; Evaluation aborted on #<SB-KERNEL:BOUNDING-INDICES-BAD-ERROR ...
CL-USER> (remove-element '(1 2 3 4 5) -1)
; Evaluation aborted on #<TYPE-ERROR ...
```